# Reconstruct a signal via continuous wavelet transform (CWT)

Tags: wavelet, reconstruction

I want to use the [continuous wavelet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform) (CWT) to modify the amplitude of a signal in the frequency domain (in a specific frequency band) and then reconstruct the signal. I want to do it by scaling the wavelet coefficients in that band. Is that the right way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: not quite clear what you want to achieve this? *every* non-identity mapping that's not an all-pass filter modifies amplitude in frequency domain...

Comment: And to second Marcus: why use the CWT?